# Open a file in python

Tags: python, pygtk

Using http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/filelisting.py how can I have the user open the file in an external program (always the same, specifically a GUI-less audio player like sox play) by clicking on it ?

```
def open_file(self, treeview, path, column):
    model = treeview.get_model()
    iter = model.get_iter(path)
    filename = os.path.join(self.dirname, model.get_value(iter, 0))
    filestat = os.stat(filename)
    if stat.S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode):
        new_model = self.make_list(filename)
        treeview.set_model(new_model)
    return
```

I guess this snippet is only about listing the files...
This would be my first python program, so please bear with me if my question is dumb :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html) or [`os.spawn`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html) or any other function that spawns or calls a process. Pass the executables name as an argument and the pass the file name as a CLI argument, as long as the called program (in your case your player) accepts CLI arguments.

Comment: He probably wants to launch it in the background, meaning he'll want to create `subprocess.Popen` and deal with it in the future (unless he wants to spawn a thread just to wait for `call` to return)… but reading the `subprocess` docs that you linked to should be enough to get him going in the right direction, so more than good enough.

Comment: `subprocess.call(["play", "~/Studio/Samples/DRUMS/Vintage_Drum_Samples_24bit/DR55/dr55_rim.wav"])` works like a charm, thank you ! Now I only have to figure out how to trigger a click event in pyGTK, and how to bind this subprocess.call to it.